# Call a shell function from command line in windows?

Tags: windows, shell

I have a windows shell script where I can call the methods from the command line.

In the shell script:

```
:build
Do something
goto:eof

:run
Do something
goto: eof
```

From the command line:

```
 script.sh build
```

I get an error:

```
 bash :build: command not found
```

How can I call the functions defined in the shell script from command line?

Comment: There is no function definition in the code you provided. You try to run a command `:build`.  bash is searching in the PATH for an executable file of this name and does not find one.

Comment: Google is your friend. For instance [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html). But honestly: With your current level of expertise, I would not start bash programming with a doing a function, which is already considered a bit advanced. Try some simple scripts first, to get a feeling for bash. Later you can learn about functions, arrays, regular expression and what else is available.

Comment: You contradict your self. You asked first for definition in bash, so this is what I refered to in my comment. Now you asking for something you call "windows function", and this does not exist, because 'windows' is not a programming language, but an operating system. For the same reason, a 'linux function'  would not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you would fix the error with `:build`, bash would next complain about `goto`. Your script is not a bash program. It looks more like a MSDOS batch file.

Comment: Ah ok. Can you please point to a documentation source? Thank you l

Comment: bash has a man-page. My impression is that you would have to learn the basics of bash programming first. There are plenty of tutorials available, for instance  [here](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners)